# How to get document ID in CustomScoreProvider?

Tags: lucene, lucene.net, scoring

In short, I am trying to determine a document's true document ID in method `CustomScoreProvider.CustomScore` which only provides a document "ID" *relative to a sub-IndexReader*.

More info: I am trying to boost my documents' scores by precomputed boost factors (imagine an in-memory structure that maps Lucene's document ids to boost factors). Unfortunately I cannot store the boosts in the index for a couple of reasons: boosting will not be used for all queries, plus the boost factors can change regularly and that would trigger a lot of reindexing.

Instead I'd like to boost the score at query time and thus I've been working with CustomScoreQuery/CustomScoreProvider. The boosting takes place in method CustomScoreProvider.CustomScore:

```
public override float CustomScore(int doc, float subQueryScore, float valSrcScore) {
   float baseScore = subQueryScore * valSrcScore;   // the default computation
   // boost -- THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS       
   float boostedScore = baseScore * MyBoostCache.GetBoostForDocId(doc); 
   return boostedScore;
}
```

My problem is with the `doc` parameter passed to CustomScore. It is not the true document id -- it is relative to the subreader used for that index segment. (The `MyBoostCache` class is my in-memory structure mapping Lucene's doc ids to boost factors.) If I knew the reader's docBase I could figure out the true id (`id = doc + docBase`).

Any thoughts on how I can determine the true id, or perhaps there's a better way to accomplish what I'm doing?

(I am aware that the id I'm trying to get is subject to change and I've already taken steps to make sure the `MyBoostCache` is always up to date with the latest ids.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by passing the IndexSearcher to my CustomScoreProvider, using it to determine which of its subreaders is being used by the CustomScoreProvider, and then getting the `MaxDoc` for the prior subreaders from the IndexSearcher to determine the docBase.

```
private int DocBase { get; set; }

public MyScoreProvider(IndexReader reader, IndexSearcher searcher) {
   DocBase = GetDocBaseForIndexReader(reader, searcher);
}

private static int GetDocBaseForIndexReader(IndexReader reader, IndexSearcher searcher) {
    // get all segment readers for the searcher
    IndexReader rootReader = searcher.GetIndexReader();
    var subReaders = new List<IndexReader>();
    ReaderUtil.GatherSubReaders(subReaders, rootReader);

    // sequentially loop through the subreaders until we find the specified reader, adjusting our offset along the way
    int docBase = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < subReaders.Count; i++)
    {
        if (subReaders[i] == reader)
            break;
        docBase += subReaders[i].MaxDoc();
    }

    return docBase;
}

public override float CustomScore(int doc, float subQueryScore, float valSrcScore) {
   float baseScore = subQueryScore * valSrcScore;
   float boostedScore = baseScore * MyBoostCache.GetBoostForDocId(doc + DocBase);
   return boostedScore;
}
```